# Is “works out of” correct English?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, expressions

I have seen people using following in corporate emails

1. He/they work(s) out of (city name)
2. He/they is/are based out of (city name)
3. He/they operate(s) out of (city name)

If someone is residing in (city name) temporarily for work purpose or has a permanent residence in that city where he works, can we use the above mentioned sentences?

If someone is **out of** somewhere how can he be **in**?

Comment: Vikram, I suspect that using "out of" in this context is just a feature of American English. It is not normally used in England and the rest of the UK because it is verbose and unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “works out of” and “operates out of” forms are often used when mentioning the home office or home base of a person who travels (or telephones) within a large area in the course of his or her work.  It is natural to use “out of” when speaking of a person whose work often is outside a home office.

I don't recall hearing or seeing the form “based out of” at all frequently, with  “based in” being more common.

Comment: I don't much like [are based out of](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22careless+talk+costs+lives%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22are+based+out+of%22&oq=%22are+based+out+of%22&gs_l=serp.3...515425.520782.1.521237.41.27.0.0.0.7.107.1314.26j1.27.0...0.0...1c.1.9.serp.E2hwtuNRAsU&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45175338,d.d2k&fp=86c55c6e166ddfa0&biw=1396&bih=872), but that's nearly 10K written instances, so I guess we have to put up with it. Anyway, that's the correct explanation for how *based **in/at*** can equate to *based **out of***.